# How to check if any form element inside a fieldset has focus

Tags: javascript, validation, dom, focus, focusout

I want to partially validate a form by validating all elements inside a fieldset.

As a trigger for that validation, I'm listening to `focusout` events which bubble up to each fieldset.

I want to perform the validation if no form element inside that fieldset has `:focus`.

I've attempted to do like this:

```js
const fieldsets = [...document.querySelectorAll('fieldset')]

for (const fieldset of fieldsets) {
  fieldset.addEventListener('focusout', (e) => {
    let focussedElements = e.currentTarget.querySelectorAll(':focus');
    if (focussedElements.length === 0) {
      console.log(`no element inside fieldset #${e.currentTarget.id} has focus`)
    } else if (focussedElements.length > 0) {
      console.log(`element ${focussedElements[0]} inside fieldset #${e.currentTarget.id} has focus`)
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="fs1">
  <legend>Fieldset 1</legend>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="fs2">
  <legend>Fieldset 2</legend>
  <input type="text">
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</fieldset>
```

but `e.currentTarget.querySelectorAll(':focus')` always has `length`of `0`.

**How do I reliably check if a `fieldset` has a child element that has `:focus`?**

Note: I don't want to use jQuery or any other library for the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you just need to wait for the focus on the new element to happen? Like this:

```js
const fieldsets = [...document.querySelectorAll('fieldset')]

for (const fieldset of fieldsets) {
  fieldset.addEventListener('focusout', (e) => {
    let ct = e.currentTarget;
    setTimeout(() => {
      let focussedElements = ct.querySelectorAll(':focus');
      if (focussedElements.length === 0) {
        console.log(`no element inside fieldset #${ct.id} has focus`)
      } else if (focussedElements.length > 0) {
        console.log(`element ${focussedElements[0]} inside fieldset #${ct.id} has focus`)
      }
    }, 10)
  })
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="fs1">
  <legend>Fieldset 1</legend>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="fs2">
  <legend>Fieldset 2</legend>
  <input type="text">
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: So this would mean that `focusin` only occurs after all handlers of `focusout` have been resolved?

Comment: I'm not sure that's guaranteed. But it's my understanding that the focusin and focusout events have been queued, so the timeout event will get queued for service after them, and so the focusin handlers will have been run by the time the timeout event handler happens.