# Incorrect focusout trigger when changing focus within container

Tags: javascript, html, focus, lost-focus

Suppose I've got the Code structure below. If I focus an element within my red container (one of the inputs), the `focusin` event triggers. Likewise, if I click outside the red container, the `focusout` event triggers.

However, if I click one of the input elements, then directly the other, both a `focusout` and a `focusin` event get triggered in quick succession.

Is there an easy way to avoid this or find out whether the second `focusout` event can be ignored because focus in fact stays within the relevant element, aside from ugly solutions like setting a flag on the first `focusout` event and waiting for a render tick to see whether another `focusin` event happens?

```js
document.getElementById("el").addEventListener("focusin", 
  () => document.getElementById("out").innerHTML += "focusin<br/>");
document.getElementById("el").addEventListener("focusout", 
  () => document.getElementById("out").innerHTML += "focusout<br/>");
```

```html
<div id="el" style="background-color: red; padding: 4px">
<input />
<input />
</div>
<div id="out">

</div>
```

Comment: You can track focus from the parent and only fire focusout if the parent no longer has an active child. see: [How to check if element has focused child using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53370088/how-to-check-if-element-has-focused-child-using-javascript)

Comment: For some reason, the active element during the temporary focusout seems to be the body element, so apparently the container item truly looses focus for a quick moment, so this won't work, right? (See https://jsfiddle.net/lukasbach/cof08qdr/8/)

Comment: You're right, I just noticed that too. I guess you'll need to check on the next focusin event. Some little discussion here: [How to check if any form element inside a fieldset has focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52079711/how-to-check-if-any-form-element-inside-a-fieldset-has-focus)

Answer (score 0):

As there doesn't seem to be an easy solution, I've wrote the ugly solution of waiting for the next render tick. I wrote it as reusable React hook, so if it helps someone, here it is.

```
export const useFocusWithin = (
  element: HTMLElement | undefined,
  onFocusIn?: () => void,
  onFocusOut?: () => void,
) => {
  const [focusWithin, setFocusWithin] = useState(false);
  const isLoosingFocusFlag = useRef(false);

  useHtmlElementEventListener(element, 'focusin', () => {
    setFocusWithin(true);
    onFocusIn?.();
    if (isLoosingFocusFlag.current) {
      isLoosingFocusFlag.current = false;
    }
  });
  
  useHtmlElementEventListener(element, 'focusout', (e) => {
    isLoosingFocusFlag.current = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (isLoosingFocusFlag.current) {
        onFocusOut?.();
        isLoosingFocusFlag.current = false;
        setFocusWithin(false);
      }
    });
  });

  return focusWithin;
};

export const useHtmlElementEventListener = <K extends keyof HTMLElementEventMap>(
  element: HTMLElement | undefined, type: K, listener: (this: HTMLElement, ev: HTMLElementEventMap[K]) => any) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (element) {
      element.addEventListener(type, listener as any);
      return () => element.removeEventListener(type, listener as any);
    }
  }, [element, listener, type]);
};
```